# java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy96 cannot be cast to ticket.app.DatesFacade

Tags: java, jsf, junit, hudson

I am entering some code into a Hudson Server run on a Ubuntu box in order to run some Code Metrics(Sonar) and Cobertura on the code. The project runs off of Glassfish3.1, uses Maven3, written in Java, JSF 2.0 and uses OracleXE Database(irrelevant).

The error is being thrown when trying to create an instance of an Facade inside of my JUnit tests. The tests run fine when I am running them from Netbeans, but when Hudson does the automatic build on it I get this error:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy96 cannot be cast to ticket.app.DatesFacade
    at ticket.app.EventsControllerTest.setUp(EventsControllerTest.java:60)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnitTestSet.execute(JUnitTestSet.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

The Hudson server is not run off of JBoss, it is run off of Tomcat. I add this detail because when I Google this error, I have found nothing but JBoss errors explaining that the facade is referenced in both the WAR and EAR files.

**EDIT:** This is how I am currently creating instances of the Facade (Which works fine when running the tests through Netbeans GF3.1):

```
        Map properties = new HashMap();
    properties.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, new File("target/classes"));
    properties.put("org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.glassfish.configuration.file", "server/config/domain.xml");
    properties.put("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "server/lib/ojdbc14.jar");
    ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
    ctx = ejbContainer.getContext();

    EventsFacade instance = (EventsFacade)ctx.lookup("java:global/classes/EventsFacade");
```

**EDIT:** My EventsFacade:

```
@Stateful
public class EventsFacade extends AbstractFacade<Events> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "tickets_AppTicket_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public EventsFacade() {
        super(Events.class);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: And.. my AbstractFacade in full:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
private Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

public void remove(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
}

public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}

public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
}

public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}
```

}

**EDIT:** Created new Interface:

```
    @Local
public interface EventsInterface<Events> {

    int count();

    void create(Events entity);

    void edit(Events entity);

    Events find(Object id);

    List<Events> findAll();

    List<Events> findRange(int[] range);

    void remove(Events entity);

}
```

**CHANGED:** EventsFacade delaration:

```
public class EventsFacade extends AbstractFacade<Events> implements EventsInterface<Events> {
```

**EDIT:** After getting the proxy error in my IDE after creating the new interface the output began to show:

```
Field Name == intfClass
Field == interface ticket.app.EventsInterface
Field Name == containerId
Field == 85313541807800321
Field Name == delegate
Field == com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler@72b0f2b2
Field Name == isOptionalLocalBusinessView
Field == false
```

Comment: and now the `AbstractFacade` definition :)

Comment: @Bozho - Just posted lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This usually means that you are referencing an object by its class, rather than by its interface when there is a proxy around the object (and the proxy is based on the interface).

The solution is to refer to the object by its interface. I would guess that `EventsFacade` has a `Local` and/or `Remote` interface. Try using that. If it doesn't have an interface - make one, it is a good practice. Define all the public methods in the interface.

Update: as it seems, this might be a problem with the embedded glassfish you are using. As you can't debug that with a debugger, here's what you can do to trace the problem: Use `java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getInvocationHandler(object)`. And then list all the fields of the returned object. (You would have to drop the cast for now and get it from the context simply as `Object`). Something like:

```
Object ic = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(facade);
Field[] fields = ic.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + field.get(ic);
}
```

Comment: Entity Facades implement the oracle.jbo.Entity interface right?
My call for the facade is like this:

        EventsFacade instance = (EventsFacade)ctx.lookup("java:global/classes/EventsFacade");

If I am to reference it by the interface, how would I make the call?

Comment: @ninn - well, I can't know what are your classes. But if the interface is `Entity`, then you should use that. Or find a mechanism to get the original object from the proxy.

Comment: Would the call then be something like:
`EventsFacade instance = (EventsFacade)ctx.lookup(oracle.jbo.Entity);`
Where ctx is the Context of the EJBContainer?

Comment: @ninn - add this to your original question. It is not quite readable here.

Comment: @ninn - well, if you are running it on tomcat, this means you don't have an EJB provider at all? Can you try using the embedded glassfish: http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/

Comment: @Bozho - I have a dependency for the:
`glasshfish-embedded-all version 3.1` in my POM already. Wouldn't this do the same?

Comment: @ninn yeah, it should. Could you inspect (With a debugger) what is the actual invocation handler of the proxy you are given.

Comment: @Bozho - I don't really believe I can. The error only occurs when running off of the Hudson(ubuntu) server. I don't receive any proxy errors while running locally. Or am I mis-understanding your question?

Comment: @ninn you are understanding it right, yeah. I forgot about that point. In that case - could you add some reflection to obtain the invocation handler programtically? See my update how.

Comment: @Bozho - Then simply do a `System.out.prinln(java.lang.reflectProxy.getInvocationHandler(object)` ?

Comment: @ninn - not exactly. Inspect the object with reflection (object.getClass().getFields()`) and print all of them, together with their values.

Comment: @Bozho - I just made an edit to my original post, I've never used reflectProxy before so I don't really know how it works. Please see my edit for my next question.

Comment: @Bozho - Now we're talking.. I'm uploading the changes to Hudson now. Give me about 5-8 minutes for the build to complete then I'll get back to you with the results.

Comment: @ninn - by the way, does this facade have a remote or local interface (as it is an EJB, I guess) ?

Comment: @Bozho - As I am sure you can tell, I'm fairly new to Enterprise Java Beans.. If my ideal of local vs remote is correct. Local runs the view off of the same server? -So, it would be local.

Comment: @Bozho - Hudson doesn't seem to want to give me the output.. Either that, or there are no fields to display.

Comment: @ninn strange. see my update from a few minutes ago advising you to create an interface, and try again.

Comment: @Bozho - I will attempt to create an interface, but I've never done so before. If you have any good tutorials or examples I would appreciate it much.

Comment: @ninn - your IDE should have an option to extract an interface, it is that easy (Then just annotate it with `@Local`)

Comment: @Bozho - Since the facade `extends AbstractFacade implements EventsInterface` should the `EventsInterface` contain all of `AbstractFacade`'s public methods also?

Comment: @ninn - it can. or it can extend from another, Base interface that has the abstract class methods.

Comment: @Bozho - I apologize for my ignorance. Do I `Extract Interface` from the `Events Entity Class` or from the `EventsFacade`? When I attempt to extract from the facade, it says there is nothing to extract.

Comment: @ninn - then just take all public methods and make an interface. For the sake of testing the above code. Later you can fix your hierarchies

Comment: @Bozho - My Abstract Facade holds the methods, should I create an interface for it then just have all of my Facades implement that interface?

Comment: @Bozho - Just made some edits to my org. post.. Do you want me to try running the Hudson Build again?

Comment: @Bozho - Should I now change my lookups to search for the `Interface`?

Comment: @ninn - no, I don't think so.

Comment: @Bozho - I am now getting the Proxy error inside of my IDE and Hudson is saying that the lookup for my EventsFacade has failed.

Comment: @Bozho - The IDE is now giving an output of:

`intfClass=interface ticket.app.EventsInterface
containerId=85313464911659009
delegate=com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler@48586403
isOptionalLocalBusinessView=false`

For where we collected the class and it's fields.

Comment: To make the output a little more clear, I changed the format and posted it as an edit on my org. post.